# How do I update the value of the record in the table without changing its ordinal number in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

For example, if I change a value of any record, it will be updated again but then it is pushed back to the last position, just like deleting and adding another record.

Comment: A position is based on a sort order. How do you order? Using a timestamp sounds logical to me, but I don't know about your use case.

Comment: Rows in a table have no implied sort order, so there is no such thing as "the last position". If you need a result in a specific sort order, you have to use `ORDER BY` in your SELECT statement. There is no alternative.

Comment: for example I have 3 records in the table in order: 1, 2, 3. If I update record 2, the order will be changed to: 1, 3, 2. What I want is the order remains must be 1, 2, 3

Comment: Use `order by the_column` when you query the table, then you get the rows in a sorted way. Using `order by` is the **only** way to guarantee a required sort order.

Comment: Looks like your queries don't use an ORDER BY and you assume that the on disk location is the "correct" order. Without ORDER BY, there is no sort order, just output. And that output might be in the same order over and over again, until a query plan, update or something else changes that "order".

Answer (score 1):

Without an ORDER BY clause, rows will be returned in whatever order is most convenient to the database engine.

In a simple SELECT, rows will usually be returned in the order they're stored on disk, and that can change at any time if the table is updated, vacuum'd, cluster'd or backed up and restored, but...

If the columns you select allow the database to do an index-only scan, then rows will be returned in a different order than when a table scan is used.

If it decides to do an index-scan, it will probably return the rows in index order, but if it does a bitmap index scan or a seq scan, it will probably be table order on disk.

If your SELECT uses a JOIN, then it will scan one of the tables first, and that will influence the order of returned rows.

If it decides to use a hash-join or a merge-join or some other type of join, then the row order will also change.

It's a common beginner mistake to forget that tables are sets, and select results are also sets, and sets are unordered. If your code relies on the order of unordered things, then it will not work.

If you want a specific order, then you must use ORDER BY.